# How to fix problems with dependencies while installing google app engine plugin on the adt bundle?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins, dependencies

I want to create an android app that requires a backend. I plan to use the google app engine. I have downloaded the adt bundle and installed all necessary packages using the sdk manager. But now when i try to install the google plugin using this link

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

I get the following message

```
(com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plugin 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Cloud Endpoints Core Tooling 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Cloud Endpoints App Engine Tooling 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm_backend 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm_backend 0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out how to come around this problem. I had to install maven integration using this link : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Following which i could install the google plugin without any dependency problems.